# Antlr4 parsing jsp scriptlets expression directive

Tags: java, html, antlr4, jsp-tags

I want to parse jsp files to identify the directive tags, jsp action elements, scriptlet expression etc. For that I am trying to extend the existing html [grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/html).
I am facing problem in differentiating normal html tag opening and jsp tag opening. The existing grammar has the following lexer rules:

```
TAG_OPEN
    : '<' -> pushMode(TAG)
    ;
//
// tag declarations
//
mode TAG;

TAG_CLOSE
    : '>' -> popMode
    ;

TAG_SLASH_CLOSE
    : '/>' -> popMode
    ;

TAG_SLASH
    : '/'
    ;

//
// lexing mode for attribute values
//
TAG_EQUALS
    : '=' -> pushMode(ATTVALUE)
    ;

TAG_NAME
    : TAG_NameStartChar TAG_NameChar*
    | TAG_NameStartChar* ':' TAG_NameStartChar*
    ;

TAG_WHITESPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;
```

And the correspoding parser rule for that:

```
htmlElement
    : TAG_OPEN htmlTagName htmlAttribute* TAG_CLOSE htmlContent TAG_OPEN TAG_SLASH htmlTagName TAG_CLOSE
    | TAG_OPEN htmlTagName htmlAttribute* TAG_SLASH_CLOSE
    | TAG_OPEN htmlTagName htmlAttribute* TAG_CLOSE
    | TAG_OPEN TAG_SLASH htmlTagName TAG_CLOSE
//  | jspDirective
//  | jspDeclaration
    | scriptlet
    | script
    | style
    ;
```

I am trying to extend the above rules with the following:

```
scriptlet
    : JSP_TAG_OPEN jspElement jspElementName jspElementAttribute* JSP_TAG_CLOSE 
    //|SCRIPTLET
    ;

jspElementName
    : TAG_NAME
    ;

jspElementAttribute
    : jspAttributeName TAG_EQUALS jspAttributeValue
    ;

jspAttributeName
    : TAG_NAME
    ;

jspAttributeValue
    : ATTVALUE_VALUE
    ;

jspElement
    : jspDirective
    | jspExpression
    | jspDeclaration
    | jspFragment
    ;

jspDirective    
    : JSP_DIRECTIVE_SIGN
    ;

jspExpression
    : JSP_EXPRESSION_SIGN
    ;

jspDeclaration
    : JSP_DECLARATION_SIGN
    ;

jspFragment
    : JSP_FRAGMENT_SIGN
    ;
```

The lexer rules are :

```
JSP_TAG_OPEN
    : '<%' ' '*
    ;

JSP_DIRECTIVE_SIGN
    : '@'
    ;

JSP_EXPRESSION_SIGN
    : '='
    ;

JSP_DECLARATION_SIGN
    : '!'
    ;

JSP_FRAGMENT_SIGN
    : [ ]+
    ;

JSP_TAG_CLOSE
    : '%>'  
    ;
```

But the problem I guess is that, whenever a `<` character is encountered the lexer rule for `TAG_OPEN` starts running, rather than waiting to see whether that is a jsp tag `<%`.

So when I am trying to parse a small html with the following content:

```
<html>
<title>Statement Load page</title>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html"
    prefix="html"%>
```

I am getting this error:

```
line 3:2 no viable alternative at input '@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html"\r\n\tprefix="html"%>\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have come up with a grammar for jsp now. I am sharing this here if that helps other people. Also, I would be glad if someone suggest any update, points out issues or helps make the grammar better.

Lexer Grammar:

```
lexer grammar  HTMLLexer;


HTML_COMMENT
    : '<!--' .*? '-->'
    ;

HTML_CONDITIONAL_COMMENT
    : '<![' .*? ']>'
    ;

JSP_COMMENT
    : '<%--' .*? '--%>'
    ;

XML_DECLARATION
    : '<?xml' .*? '>'
    ;

SCRIPT_OPEN
    : '<script' ->pushMode(SCRIPT)
    ;

DIRECTIVE_TAG_OPEN
    : '<%@' -> pushMode(TAG)
    ;

SCRIPTLET_TAG_OPEN
    : ('<%!' | '<%=' | '<%') ->pushMode(SCRIPTVALUE)
    ;

//
//
CDATA
    : '<![CDATA[' .*? ']]>'
    ;

DTD
    : '<!' .*? '>'
    ;

//SCRIPTLET
//    : '<?' .*? '?>'
//    | '<%' .*? '%>'
//    ;

SEA_WS
    :  (' '|'\t'|'\r'? '\n')+
    ;


LINK_OPEN
    : '<link' ->pushMode(LINK)
    ;

STYLE_OPEN
    : '<style'  ->pushMode(STYLE)
    ;

TAG_OPEN
    : '<' ->pushMode(TAG)
    ;

HTML_TEXT
    : ~'<'+
    ;

//
// tag declarations
//
mode TAG;

JSP_TAG_CLOSE
    : '%>' -> popMode   
    ;

TAG_CLOSE
    : '>' -> popMode
    ;

TAG_SLASH_CLOSE
    : '/>' -> popMode
    ;

TAG_SLASH
    : '/'
    ;

//
// lexing mode for attribute values
//
TAG_EQUALS
    : '=' -> pushMode(ATTVALUE)
    ;

TAG_NAME
    : TAG_NameStartChar TAG_NameChar*
//  | TAG_NameStartChar* ':' TAG_NameStartChar*
    ;

TAG_COLON
    : ':'
    ;

TAG_WHITESPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

fragment
HEXDIGIT
    : [a-fA-F0-9]
    ;

fragment
DIGIT
    : [0-9]
    ;


TAG_NameChar
    : TAG_NameStartChar
//  | ':'
    | '-'
    | '_'
    | '.'
    | DIGIT
    |   '\u00B7'
    |   '\u0300'..'\u036F'
    |   '\u203F'..'\u2040'
    ;


TAG_NameStartChar
    :   [a-zA-Z]
    |   '\u2070'..'\u218F'
    |   '\u2C00'..'\u2FEF'
    |   '\u3001'..'\uD7FF'
    |   '\uF900'..'\uFDCF'
    |   '\uFDF0'..'\uFFFD'
    ;

//
// <scripts>
//
mode SCRIPT;

SCRIPT_TAG_FULL_CLOSE
    : '</script>' ->popMode
    ;


SCRIPT_TAG_CLOSE
    : '>' -> popMode
    ;

SCRIPT_TAG_SLASH_CLOSE
    : '/>' -> popMode
    ;

SCRIPT_EQUALS
    : ' '* '=' ' '*
    ;

SCRIPLET_INSIDE_SCRIPT
    : '<%' ->pushMode(SCRIPTVALUE)
    ;

SCRIPT_ATTRIBUTE
    : SCRIPT_ATTCHARS    
    ;

fragment SCRIPT_ATTCHARS
    : SCRIPT_ATTCHAR+ ' '?
    ;

SCRIPT_WHITESPACE
    : [\r\n\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

WORD
    : [ a-zA-Z]+
    ;

QUOTE
    : '"' ' '*
    ;

fragment SCRIPT_ATTCHAR
    : '-'
    | '_'
    | '.'
    | '/'
    | ','
    | ';'
    | '\''
    | '"'
    | [0-9a-zA-Z]
    ;       

//
// <link>
//
mode LINK;

LINK_BODY
    : .*? '</link>' ->popMode
    ;

LINK_SHORT_BODY
    : '/>' ->popMode
    ;

LINK_WS
    : [ \r\n\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

LINK_NONSLASH_BODY
    : .*? '>' ->popMode
    ;


//
// <styles>
//
mode STYLE;

STYLE_BODY
    : .*? '</style>' -> popMode
    ;

STYLE_SHORT_BODY
    : .*? '</>' -> popMode
    ;

//
// attribute values
//
mode ATTVALUE;

// an attribute value may have spaces b/t the '=' and the value
ATTVALUE_VALUE
    : [ ]* ATTRIBUTE -> popMode
    ;

ATTRIBUTE
    : DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING
    | SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING
    | ATTCHARS
    | HEXCHARS
    | DECCHARS
    ;

fragment ATTCHAR
    : '-'
    | '_'
    | '.'
    | '/'
    | '+'
    | ','
    | '?'
    | '='
    | ':'
    | ';'
    | '#'
    | [0-9a-zA-Z]
    ;

fragment ATTCHARS
    : ATTCHAR+ ' '?
    ;

fragment HEXCHARS
    : '#' [0-9a-fA-F]+
    ;

fragment DECCHARS
    : [0-9]+ '%'?
    ;

fragment DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING
    : '"' ~[<"]* '"'
    ;
fragment SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING
    : '\'' ~[<']* '\''
    ;

mode SCRIPTVALUE;

SCRIPTLET_TAG_CLOSE
    : '%>' ->popMode
    ;

VALID_JAVA_CHARS
    : SCRIPTCHARS+
    ;

SCRIPT_WS
    : [\r\n\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

fragment SCRIPTCHARS
    : SCRIPTCHAR+ ' '?
    ;   

fragment SCRIPTCHAR
    : '-'
    | '_'
    | '.'
    | '/'
    | '+'
    | ','
    | '?'
    | '='
    | ':'
    | ';'
    | '#'
    | '('
    | ')'
    | '}'
    | '{'
    | '@'
    | '*'
    | '!'
    | '%'[0-9]+
    | '&'
    | '['
    | ']'
    | '~'
    | '+'
    | '^'
    | '\r'
    | '\t'
    | '\n'
    | ' '
    | '"'
    | '\''
    | [0-9a-zA-Z]
    ;
```

Parser Grammar:

```
parser grammar HTMLParser;

options { tokenVocab=HTMLLexer; }

htmlDocument
    : (scriptlet | SEA_WS)* xml? (scriptlet | SEA_WS)* dtd? (scriptlet | SEA_WS)* htmlElements*
    ;

htmlElements
    : htmlMisc* htmlElement htmlMisc*
    ;

htmlElement
    : script
    | link
    | style
    | scriptlet
    | TAG_OPEN htmlTagName htmlAttribute* TAG_CLOSE htmlContent TAG_OPEN TAG_SLASH htmlTagName TAG_CLOSE
    | TAG_OPEN htmlTagName htmlAttribute* TAG_SLASH_CLOSE
    | TAG_OPEN htmlTagName htmlAttribute* TAG_CLOSE
    | TAG_OPEN TAG_SLASH htmlTagName TAG_CLOSE
    ;

htmlContent
    : htmlChardata? ((htmlElement | xhtmlCDATA | htmlComment) htmlChardata?)*
    ;

htmlAttribute
    : htmlAttributeName TAG_EQUALS htmlAttributeValue
    | htmlAttributeName
    ;

htmlAttributeName
    : TAG_NAME
    ;

htmlAttributeValue
    : ATTVALUE_VALUE
    ;

htmlTagName
    : TAG_NAME
    | tagKey TAG_COLON tagVal
    ;

tagKey
    : TAG_NAME
    ;

tagVal
    : TAG_NAME
    ;

htmlChardata
    : HTML_TEXT
    | SEA_WS
    ;

htmlMisc
    : htmlComment
    | jspComment
    | SEA_WS
    ;

htmlComment
    : HTML_COMMENT
    | HTML_CONDITIONAL_COMMENT
    ;

jspComment
    : JSP_COMMENT
    ;

xhtmlCDATA
    : CDATA
    ;

dtd
    : DTD
    ;

xml
    : XML_DECLARATION
    ;

scriptlet
    : DIRECTIVE_TAG_OPEN jspElementName jspElementAttribute* JSP_TAG_CLOSE 
    | SCRIPTLET_TAG_OPEN javaExpression SCRIPTLET_TAG_CLOSE
    ;

jspElementName
    : TAG_NAME
    ;

jspElementAttribute
    : jspAttributeName TAG_EQUALS jspAttributeValue
    ;

jspAttributeName
    : TAG_NAME
    ;

jspAttributeValue
    : ATTVALUE_VALUE
    ;

javaExpression
    : VALID_JAVA_CHARS | SEA_WS*    
    ;

script
    : SCRIPT_OPEN scriptAttribute* SCRIPT_TAG_CLOSE htmlContent* SCRIPT_TAG_FULL_CLOSE
    | SCRIPT_OPEN scriptAttribute* SCRIPT_TAG_SLASH_CLOSE
    ;

scriptAttribute
    : scriptAttributeName SCRIPT_EQUALS QUOTE scriptlet scriptAttributeValue* QUOTE
    | scriptAttributeName SCRIPT_EQUALS scriptAttributeValue
    | scriptAttributeName
    ;

scriptAttributeName
    : WORD
    ;   

scriptAttributeValue
    : SCRIPT_ATTRIBUTE
    ;

link
    : LINK_OPEN ( LINK_BODY | LINK_SHORT_BODY | LINK_NONSLASH_BODY)
    | LINK_OPEN scriptlet* ( LINK_BODY | LINK_SHORT_BODY | LINK_NONSLASH_BODY)
    ;

style
    : STYLE_OPEN ( STYLE_BODY | STYLE_SHORT_BODY)
    ;
```

Edit: I have modified the Parser and Lexer grammar since my last entry. I am facing problem in parsing a jsp file now. A sample jsp is:

```
<html>
<title>Statement Load page</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/scripts/Main.js"></script>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

While parsing this file, I am getting :

```
line 4:0 mismatched input '<script' expecting '<'
line 5:31 no viable alternative at input '<script type="text/javascript" src'
```

That is, while encountering "<script" tag the parser is not entering the 'script' rule, but probably treating it as other 'htmlElement'. But I am not sure.

The relevant portion of the parser grammar is:

```
script
    : SCRIPT_OPEN scriptAttribute* SCRIPT_TAG_CLOSE htmlContent* SCRIPT_TAG_FULL_CLOSE
    | SCRIPT_OPEN scriptAttribute* SCRIPT_TAG_SLASH_CLOSE
    ;

scriptAttribute
    : scriptAttributeName SCRIPT_EQUALS QUOTE scriptlet scriptAttributeValue* QUOTE
    | scriptAttributeName SCRIPT_EQUALS scriptAttributeValue
    | scriptAttributeName
    ;

scriptAttributeName
    : WORD
    ;   

scriptAttributeValue
    : SCRIPT_ATTRIBUTE
    ;
```

Comment: I have been modifying my grammar to parse the script tag in more details. But I am facing problem while parsing. @Bart Kiers could you please take a look into this.